# weight/window functions with constant sum for infinite discrete sampling, like triangle functions

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Imagine a function $w_n(x) : R \rightarrow R , n \in N$ such that:

$w_n(x) = 0  , \forall x \notin [-nL, nL], L \in R $

$ 1 = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} w_n(x - kL), k \in N, \forall x \in R$

I know there are many possible $w_n(x)$ functions. For example, for $ n = 1 $, the triangle function simply works , but I'm looking for smoother functions which work for any n (you can make it work for any n with triangle functions but it's just not smooth).

Also, with the aim of adding a context, I'm doing this because I want to implement a lightfield renderer [using this paper](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmiuKF39LNAhXEPRQKHaFyCUsQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.harvard.edu%2F~sjg%2Fpapers%2Fdrlf.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGUIZq8ioz6vOvMi3IdpMs9gaJaGw&sig2=ORKbgOZMgZLPOAI1qHjPhg) . You can see some example functions like the triangle function in page 3, Figure 6:

[image: image from paper[2]]

On that picture, you can see that functions $ w_2 $ and $w_3 $ but unfortunately I just don't know which functions are, although they look similar to a variation of $ {sin (\pi x) \over \pi x } {1 \over 1 + |x|^2 } $

What kind of functions $w_n$ do you know and what is their name so that I can look them up?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this and I think I have at least an answer on how to build $ w_n (x) $ functions.

First, I have to argue why the $ sinc(x) $ function and its variations are quite nice. The following will assume L = 1. Let's define a sample function:

$ sample(x, func) = \sum\limits_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} w_n(x - k) $

If we use the bare $ sinc(x) $, without limiting it with $ rect(x/M) $, then:

$ sample(x, sinc) = 1, \forall x \in R $

So, in the limit ($ n \rightarrow \infty$), the $ sinc(x) $ function is what we want. But what happens if we limit it with $ f(x) = sinc(x) rect(x /6)$?

Then $ sample(x, f) \neq 1, \forall x \in R$ , but it's somewhat close, as you can see:

[sample(x,f)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xOL7.png)

So the sample function oscillates between 1 and 1.1. Now the idea is simply to "normalize" f by dividing it by the sample function!

$ f(x) = sinc(x) rect(x /6)$

$ g(x) = { f(x) \over sample(x, f) } $

In this picture you can see the difference between f and g:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Wxe.png)

EDIT: I've found out that while the previous explanation works, a smoother and well-known function is the Lanczos kernel:

$ k(x) = sinc(x) sinc({x \over a}) rect({x \over 2a}) $

The lanczos kernel also has the property $ 1 = sample(x, k) $